# ChartJS bar chart with legend which corresponds to each bar

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to understand the ChartJS documentation on their bar chart. It doesn't make a log of sense to me as the label at the top in once sense looks as though it applies to just the first bar (based on color) and in another sense, the entire chart (it is the only label that's not in a tooltip and it is front and center)

[image: bar chart demo]

I've been struggling to make it more like their line chart, which shows a legend with a label and a colored square related to each line on the chart. (they haven't got an example of a multiline chart, but it does work like this).

The labels property within the data object gets translated to the value next to the bar, eg `labels: ['36%', '10%', '18%', '34%', '0%', '2%']`
[image: bar chart fail]

I want a legend at the top that indicates the aqua color is apples, the grey is oranges, the green is pears, etc, but the closest I've come is providing `data.datasets` an array of objects and making labels and array, which only results in groups of bars, like the example [here](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/XjAjaG?editors=1010).

Comment: Just create a data set for each type, they dont have to have more than one bar.

Comment: @Blindman67  can you show me what you mean? That sounds quite similar to what I tried when combining an array of labels along with an array of datasets, but I'm super new to this so maybe I didn't get it correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to do this, to create multiple items in the datasets, each having data for only one category. You can have one top level label called stock and then create the individual data-sets for each type.

```js
// create a chart.
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: "horizontalBar",
   data: {
      labels: ["Stock"],
      datasets: [{
         label: "Apples",
         backgroundColor: "#AF7",
         data: [Math.random() * 100],
      },{
         label: "Oranges",
         backgroundColor: "#FA4",
         data: [Math.random() * 100],
      },{
         label: "Mangos",
         backgroundColor: "#FF7",
         data: [Math.random() * 100],
      },{
         label: "Avocados",
         backgroundColor: "#2A7",
         data: [Math.random() * 100],
      }]
   },
   options: {
          responsive: false,
          legend: { position: 'top'},
          title: { display: true, text: 'Fruit in stock'}
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id=canvas height=200 width=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Instead of just "Stock" at the left, is there anyway to put a separate label for each bar, eg `18, 82, 22, 80` going down the y-axis?

Comment: I did have a look but could not find a way to do that, though that does not mean its not possible

Comment: you can add to the x axis, stacked: true and add multiple labels

Comment: @Omran that doesn't really work for me. any ideas?

Comment: @momal i am doing this `{scales: {xAxes: [{stacked: true, ...}]}, ...}` and it is working for me

Comment: does this work in ChartJS 4?