# Chart JS 3.9 - bar chart with multiple legend labels for one dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js, label, legend

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQPUx.png)

As seen in this picture, I would like additional legends that is matching the colors.

Like Apples are shown with the color green, I would also like to show 'Bananas' for orange', 'Grapes' for yellow, etc.

Here is my current code:

```
const data = {
    labels: [19, 9, 15, 9, 1],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Apples',
      backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
          'rgb(255, 100, 0)',
          'rgb(100, 100, 0)',
          'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
          'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
      ],
      data: [19, 9, 15, 9, 1],
    },
    ]
};
```

How can I get the legend labels to match my data set? For some reason, I can't specify 'label' in the datasets as an array, only as a single string.

If I use multiple datasets instead, all the charts group together on the 'label' 19

Comment: Then I think you need to create different datsets for each element (dataset object 1 = apples, dataset object 2 = bananas, etc)

Comment: Yeah tried that, but then they all stack together like this, which is not what i want:
https://i.imgur.com/vAIhOCc.png

Comment: I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297428/chartjs-bar-chart-with-legend-which-corresponds-to-each-bar

Comment: @PeterDalby of course, because you need to change as well the labels param to just one element (e.g. "Fruits). This is also done in the link user2057925
 shares